# Exits and beeps on Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, assumptions

Evaluating

```
$Version
(*12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)*)

Clear["Global`*"];
ineq1 = r[2]+y r[3]>r[1]+y r[2]&&(-1+y) r[2]+r[4]<y r[3];
reg1=ImplicitRegion[ineq1,{{r[1],0,1},{r[2],0,1},{r[3],0,1},{r[4],0,1}}];
int[y_]=Assuming[1>y>0,Integrate[y r[2],{r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4]}\[Element]reg1]]
```

beeps with no output.

"Why the beep?" explains "The kernal Local has quit(exited) during the course of an evaluation)

Do Windows/Mac users experience the same? Is the error elsewhere?

Comment: Reproduced on 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019). The kernel should not crash. Please report to Wolfram Support. Using `SetDelayed` and specifying a value for `y` seems to work. `int[y_] := ...`, `int[0.5]`.

Comment: Thanks. Just reported.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi - on my Mac with v12, `int[0.5]` erroneously evaluates to a complicated `Piecewise` function of `y`.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I was not able to replicate the complicated Piecewise function in this case, although in other similar problems I've gotten complicated piecewise functions. What code did you specifically run?

Answer (score 2):

This is an **extended comment** to demonstrate the results on my system

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

ineq1 = r[2] + y r[3] > r[1] + y r[2] && (-1 + y) r[2] + r[4] < y r[3];

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[
   ineq1, {{r[1], 0, 1}, {r[2], 0, 1}, {r[3], 0, 1}, {r[4], 0, 1}}];

int[y_] := 
 Assuming[1 > y > 0, 
  Integrate[y r[2], {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]} ∈ reg1]]

int[0.5]
```

[image]

```
% // Simplify[#, 0 < y < 1] &
```

[image]

Since `int[0.5]` has a numeric value for `y`, the symbol `y` should not appear in the evaluated output.

Presumably, it is a scoping issue which is avoided by explicitly passing `y` as a parameter to `ineq1` and `reg1`

```
Clear["Global`*"];

ineq1[y_] := r[2] + y r[3] > r[1] + y r[2] && (-1 + y) r[2] + r[4] < y r[3];

reg1[y_] := 
  ImplicitRegion[
   ineq1[y], {{r[1], 0, 1}, {r[2], 0, 1}, {r[3], 0, 1}, {r[4], 0, 1}}];

int[y_] := 
 Assuming[1 > y > 0, 
  Integrate[y r[2], {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]} ∈ reg1[y]]]

int[0.5]

(* 0.09375 *)
```